# Asymtotic run time needed to compute the transitive closure of a graph?

Tags: language-agnostic, runtime, theory, graph-theory

The transitive closure of a graph is defined e. g. here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitiveClosure.html

It is easily possible in O(n^3), where n is the number of vertices. I was wondering if it can be done in time O(n^2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. I don't think there is a O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm for it. I would expect if such an algorithm existed, you could solve all pair shortest paths problem in O(n<sup>2</sup>) too, which is not the case. The asymptotically fastest algorithm I can think of is an implementation of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm with a Fibonacci heap (O(*n*<sup>2</sup>log *n*) in not very dense graphs).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I found an algorithm that computes the transitive closure in O(n^2) EXPECTED run time.

Comment: with which random distribution?

Comment: no idea. i don't want to use it, because i don't want any randomization in my surrounding algorithm. it's here: http://www.springerlink.com/content/f511w61n62l17168/

Answer (score 1):

Given that this:

> Can you come up with an O(kn^2 + m) transitive closure/reduction 
>   algorithm, where k is the number of missing/extra edges in the transitive 
>   closure/reduction?

Is still considered an open question by people who think about these sorts of things more than we do, I'd say "I don't know".

(But if you solve it and want a PhD, I know *that* algorithm.)